# Convert autosys Jil to CSV using shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I have an autosys api url which has Jil script available . I need a shell script which can fetch the data from web url and use it as a text to convert it to CSV file. For few jobs, there are repeated parameters used
For eg: envvars with seperate values mentioned twice in job2

Url: https://jildesctiption:instance/file.txt

```
/* ----------------- somejob ----------------- */ 

insert_job: somejob   job_type: CMD 
command: SAS ${AUTO_ROOT}/pgms/somejob.sas
machine: someserver.com
owner: user1
permission: gx,wx
date_conditions: 1
run_calendar: 1st_bus_dom
start_times: "07:00"
condition: s(someotherjob)
description: "Send email notification."
std_out_file: "${AUTO_JOB_LOG}.out"
std_err_file: "${AUTO_JOB_LOG}.err"
alarm_if_fail: 1
profile: "/foo/bar/etc/app1"
alarm_if_terminated: 1
timezone: CST6CDT
group: grp1
application: app1
envvars: autojob:python 
resources: (someresource,QUANTITY=2,FREE=A)

/* ----------------- somejob2 ---------------- */ 

insert_job: somejob2   job_type: CMD 
command: SAS ${AUTO_ROOT}/pgms/somejob2.sas
machine: someserver.com
owner: user1
permission: gx,wx
date_conditions: 1
run_calendar: 1st_bus_dom
start_times: "07:00"
condition: s(someotherjob)
description: "Send email notification": AFDG"
std_out_file: "${AUTO_JOB_LOG}.out"
std_err_file: "${AUTO_JOB_LOG}.err"
alarm_if_fail: 1
envvars: abc
envvars: qph
profile: "/foo/bar/etc/app1"
alarm_if_terminated: 1
timezone: CST6CDT
group: grp1
application: app1
resources: (someresource,QUANTITY=2,FREE=A)
```

I have tried below awk command to fetch the data in CSV format with delimiter as "^"

```
#!/bin/sh

curl -L https://jildesctiption:instance/file.txt > File1.txt

sed -i -e '/description: "/s/: /- /2' File1.txt    
sed 's/ \(job_type:\)/\ \1/' File1.txt  | sed -e 's/^[\t]*//' |
awk -F ': ' 'BEGIN {
 h="insert_job;owner;envvars; description; application;profile"; print h; 
n=split(h,F,/;/)
}
function pr() {
   if (F[1] in A) 
     (for(i=1;i<=n;i++)printf "%s%s", A[F[i]],(i<n)?"^":RS
   }
}
/insert_job/ {pr(); delete A}
# (  # typo?
  for(i in F) {
  if ($0~"^"F[i])A[F[i]]=$2}
 }
END {pr()}' > Jiltoexcel.xls
```

Challenges am facing
1- As delimiter between parameters and values in each job is ":"

I have to use different character for separating each line. here I used ^. Hence while opening excel, I have manually convert to columns using delimiter ^
2- envvars is used twice in a job. It's picking up the last value instead of giving both the values in sheet

Comment: I flagged a typo (I think) before your for loop. Good first question! But when posting code or data (or requrred output, errMsgs), mouse-select code, click on `{}` tool in Edit menu to get correct formatting as `code/data/output/errMsgs`. It also helps to have code indented to show the structure. I think I got yours right. Hmm, now that I can "see" the code, do you want that leading `(` around `for` loop in your function? Good luck.

Comment: I think I'm seeing a few other syntax problems in your `awk` code. Sorry if I have introduced them, but I was very careful in reformatting. So I think they were originally in your code. Anyway .. As above, copy/paste indented code "on-top" of the existing code and use `{}` Edit tool. Good luck.

Comment: What exact result do you want?  What result do you currently get?